# Change the Order of Fields on Teaser node.tpl

Tags: nodes

Hello i am struggling here a bit to change the display of my node teasers. I was hoping to take the title and submitted part and put it on top of my body field to the right of my teaser image. Ive tried Panelizer (looks great but the image field stays there if there is an image or not), Entity View Modes (dont know if this is really what i need) and even tried what could be the best way just simply editting the node.tpl and changing the fields about.

I think i'll just go with the last way as i did almost have it but due to a lack of knowledge and trouble finding out more ive had to ask you guys for some help.

I think i need to add

```
    <?php if ($teaser): ?>
        something in here
        <?php endif; ?>
```

but either it just not working (soz ive been up 24hs and im at the end of the line i think. Just hoping for some help either before bed or for when i get up) or else i get 2 body texts and titles appearing. I was just wanting my image on the left then to the right my title nd submitted fields above the body text.

I hate folks that do this but im gonna give it a go as im too tired to think now im sorry. here is my node.tpl Even just a good suggestion of what to do would be great. even better would be reworked code and i wont learn anything at all but i have tried. Tried for the past 4 hours

```
    <article class="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?> <?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?   php print $attributes; ?>>

      <?php if ($title_prefix || $title_suffix || $display_submitted || $unpublished ||   !$page && $title): ?>
        <header>
          <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
          <?php if (!$page && $title): ?>
            <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

          <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
            <p class="submitted">
              <?php print $user_picture; ?>
              <?php print $submitted; ?>
            </p>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if ($unpublished): ?>
            <p class="unpublished"><?php print t('Unpublished'); ?></p>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </header>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php
        // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
        hide($content['comments']);
        hide($content['links']);
        print render($content);
      ?>

      <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

      <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

    </article><!-- /.node -->
```

Thanks in advanced. Ive got to the stage where even posting code on stackexchange is hard work for me :(

Comment: My main problem before was duplicate titles and node bodies Or none at all on the node itself. As i say i went down other avenues with other modules and im back to the start where maybe i should be. thanks

Comment: You could try a simple debug to establish which view mode your in or rather if your actually using a teaser view mode by giving the $teaser variable a var_dump($teaser). For view mode use the $view_mode variable.

Comment: im just in normal teaser view mode Alex. ive created a few other view modes but i think just simply editting the node tpl would work best for me. My main problem seems to be just putting the node.tpl back together proper. Ive had 2 bodies and no bodies etc so what im doing is defo effecting the teaser. I remeber back to D6 and i used to see the teaser and the full node all on one tpl and i think im almost 'good enough' lol to go this road. I just dont know the simple basics of variables etc to do it though although i have tried.

Comment: I dont want to add anything nor take anything away i just want to have my title and submitted fields to the right of the teaser image instead of on top of it. Thanks

Comment: ps im sorry if i misunderstood your reply. I am tired.Maybe i should sleep and start afresh tomorrow.

Comment: Take your own advice Reg, your having a programmers block ;-)

Comment: lol thanks Alex. Truth of the matter is just like 6 hours ago i didnt know how to do it and now after 6 hours of trying i still dont know how to do it. Even if i was fully awake i still wouldnt know how to do it. I can almost do it i just keep buggering up the node full view when i do. The answer is probably that simple that no one on the web are talking about it as its such common fare to them. I just need an entry point somewhere with it all and i will have lovely teasers and i will sleep soundly.

Comment: In fairness Reg it should be straight forward. When you create a content type you can give it different view modes, default, teaser, etc. You can 'manage display' and order the way your fields are shown for each view mode. You shouldnt even need to touch the tpl.

Comment: Thats what i was hoping alex and maybe a wee bit of css would do the job. I need to move the title and submitted though and with everything being in the body its not happening that way for me. I dont mind doing a tpl change as i do think thats the way to go. Makes sense to me. I just dont some of the finer points of doing it :(

Comment: and before anyone suggest Display Suite im sorry im not interested lol Paneliser works great for this ive found. Just a shame i cant hide the image space id there is no image in the node. also ive got video and image content types on the same teaser list.

Comment: Get back to basics reg, copy and paste the code form node.tpl somewhere else. Then put just  <?php if ($teaser): ?> TEST <?php endif; ?> in the template. If it works as expected, build up the template with an else statement for the default view mode.

Comment: lol thats where im at Alex. that works. Its the building up the template from there tht im having problems with. If i didnt have to show the full node then there wouldnt be a problem (obviously i have to). Yes the 'build up the template with an else staement' is what i need to know.

Comment: You have everything you need in your example above, what are you missing?

Comment: lol just the know how Alex. I dont know how to JUST edit th teaser display. My code above has nothing for the teaser and although i know the code i dont know where to put it or how to stop the same code showing twice (or not at all) on my teasers.

Comment: if you was to make your teasers have an image to the left alex and the title and the body and links displayed to the right of it (instead of above it) using the code in the first post , what would you change?

Comment: again as mentioned previous ive a feeling im missing something so fundemental that no one even talks about it :(

Comment: Ill put it in an answer for you to see.

Comment: sorry alex but this is where i hav a lack of understing. Im ok etc with findign fields from devel etc i just dont know where to add the code you offer. Shall i put it to the top of my node.tpl and then let everything on there just sit below? ill go give it a try but as i say putting the code in the right places has been my problem from the off. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
<?php if ($teaser): ?>
    <?php print render($content['YOUR_IMAGE_FIELD']); ?>
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
        <?php if ($title): ?>
          <h2><?php print $title; ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php hide($content['YOUR_IMAGE_FIELD']); ?>
    <?php hide($content['links']); ?>
    <?php print render($content); ?>
    <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
<?php else: ?>
   //...show default view mode
<?php endif; ?>
```

Most of the fields are bundled together into the **$content** variable.

We can remove them from being output in the $content variable by using the **hide()** function just before we render it (see above).

We can then print the specific field anywhere we like in the template like. See above where weve put the image field.

To determine what fields you have to play with do a var_dump($content) at the top of the template or even better use the **Devel** module to do this.

Comment: ah brilliant alex thanks. Let me go try. i would say brb but that might not be the case lol

Comment: Haha no worries, let us know how you got on!

Comment: after the first else should i start from.. 
  <?php if ($title_prefix || $title_suffix || $display_submitted || $unpublished || !$page && $title): ?>

Comment: i see what your saying now and have been trying to say from the start. I need to know my specific fields. let me go try but again im still worried about where the rest of the template i posted goes after you code...

Comment: You want to put everything in your example from <?php if ($title_prefix to $content['comments']); ?> in the else statement.

Comment: thanks Alex. I found my field with devel and SOMETHING happened lol. I am not to sure its a good thing or a bad thing. let me go see.... http://onlineplac.es/komp-krap

Comment: mmmmmits kinda worked but in a not worked at all as hoped sort of way. Still its encouraging. My title seems to be still whre it was and the links have jumped up above the body which isnt as bad as it sounds. Ive got to confess alex ive been drinking the whole time whilst ive been sitting hre to stay awake. Im not going to bed though till i have pretty looking teasers. Do you have any idea of where i went wrong? thank (and i really appreciate your time and trouble)

Comment: You need to do that same thing with the $content['links'] as in the default view mode. See updated answer.

Comment: ah brill alex my links have went back. The title though is still the same as per http://onlineplac.es/komp-krap im tempted to give up but lll keep trying. Is there any way to get the title of the node over to the right and above the teaser body field (ie right of the image?) thanks

Comment: and if being a petulant child is ok can i have my bottom links directly below my teaser field too? :(

Comment: Are you sure this <?php print render($content['field_imageown']); ?> is working? Print again somewhere in the template to check.

Comment: sorry for lauging here alex but ive managed to recreate exacttly what i had before lol ... i need a pee

Comment: Ive got to go now, have a play, your work it out.

Comment: im the same alex i dont think its gonna happen is it? I think i will have to look at it agin tomorrow but thanks for all your help today. Have a good rest of the day to yourself and thanks again.

Comment: right im back. Sorry for my drunkeness alex and thanks for all your help. Let me see if i can make any sense of it all now...

Comment: You where rich Alex. I was using the wrong image field i was needing field_image_sc. Im sorry. Again thank you very much for your patience and time. all working now as per your answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to hear it Reg!

Answer (score 0):

updated node.tpl

```
    <article class="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?> <?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

    <?php if ($teaser): ?>
        <?php print render($content['field_imageown']); ?>
        <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
            <?php if ($title): ?>
              <h2><?php print $title; ?></h2>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
        <?php hide($content['field_imageown']); ?>
        <?php print render($content); ?>
    <?php else: ?>

      <?php if ($title_prefix || $title_suffix || $display_submitted || $unpublished || !$page && $title): ?>
        <header>
          <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
          <?php if (!$page && $title): ?>
            <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

          <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
            <p class="submitted">
              <?php print $user_picture; ?>
              <?php print $submitted; ?>
            </p>
          <?php endif; ?>

          <?php if ($unpublished): ?>
            <p class="unpublished"><?php print t('Unpublished'); ?></p>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </header>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php
    // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['comments']);
    hide($content['links']);
    print render($content);
  ?>

  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- /.node -->
```